# Corona TDD with busted "module 'storyboard' not found"

Tags: lua, tdd, coronasdk, lua-busted

I am writing an app in Corona and coming from a TDD background I wanted to write some unit tests for it. I installed busted via luarocks and most stuff seems to be working fine(wrote a couple small modules and test suites for each one). I begin to run into issues when the module I am testing requires a Corona library like `storyboard`, which results in the error `"module 'storyboard' not found"`

Does anyone Corona TDD experience have any suggestions? Perhaps a directory containing the Corona modules is in the Lua search path?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is your `LUA_PATH` environment variable set properly?

Comment: @RyanStein it is set. Not sure if it is set correctly though. Everything else loads fine. Strange that the `storyboard` module is required just fine in my `main.lua`(when I run the app via the simulator).

Comment: Does `LUA_PATH` include the path of Corona's libraries? Something like `./?.lua;/path/to/Corona/?.lua`. I'm assuming the simulator automatically includes that path before running.

Answer (score 0):

Check this out: https://github.com/chris-allnutt/unit-tested-corona

You can find a working example there.

I personally had problems installing busted, so I went with LunaTest instead and things are working great with Corona: 
[LunaTest and Corona](http://jessewarden.com/2012/07/unit-testing-in-corona-sdk-using-lunatest.html)

Comment: I didn't see any examples in that repo that were using the storyboard module. Can you provide an example?

Comment: Are you running the code with Corona Simulator or Lua interpreter?

I personally had lots of problems with busted and corona working together, so I decided to use Luna Test instead and things are going great! LunaTest and corona Tutorial here: http://jessewarden.com/2012/07/unit-testing-in-corona-sdk-using-lunatest.html